# iText7 RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy not finding all regex matches

Tags: c#, regex, itext, itext7

So I have been using iText7 on C# for PDF data extraction and highlighting. I used to use iTextSharp 5 and it did well for what I needed, I ported over some functionality but decided to start using the **RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy** to find the rectangles I need to highlight rather than a modified version of the **TextLocationExtractionStrategy**. The issue I am running into is that I have a PDF (unfortunately cannot share, but I am trying to create one that can reproduce the issue) that contains the word combination "Blood pressure" and I have a regex statement as follows `@"\b\.blood\spressure\b"`. I have verified this regex statement finds the match of the text on the pdf document when I extract the entire page text, but when I run it through the Regex strategy, it does not return a matching result for the same exact page. Below is the code I am using

```
            foreach (string searchTerm in Model.SearchTerms)
            {
                if (searchTerm.Contains(" "))
                {
                    var split = searchTerm.Split(" ");
                    foreach (string item in split)
                    {
                        term += item + @"\s";
                    }
                    char[] trim = new char[2] { 's', '\\' };
                    term = term.Trim(trim);
                }
                else
                {
                    term = searchTerm;
                }
                regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\b");
                regexList.Add(@"\b\." + term + @"\b");
                regexList.Add(@"\.\b" + term + @"\b");
                regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"s\b");
                regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\.\b");
                regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\s\b");
            }

            searchRegex = new Regex(string.Join('|', regexList), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
            for (int i = Model.BlankPages + 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); i++)
            {
                extractionStrategy = new RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy(searchRegex);
                canvasProcessor = new PdfCanvasProcessor(extractionStrategy);
                canvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(pdfDocument.GetPage(i));
                page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
                pageRectangles.Add(new KeyValuePair<PdfPage, List<Rectangle>>(page, extractionStrategy.GetResultantLocations().Select(x => x.GetRectangle()).ToList()));
            }
```

I have verified that the text is there and my regex works with the following

```
            for (int page = 1; page <= numberOfPages; page++)
            {
                strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
                pageText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfDocument.GetPage(page), strategy);
                pageValuePairs.Add(page, pageText);
            }
            // code break to seperate helper method where searchString is the pageText from the above code
        public static KeyValuePair<Regex, bool> FindString(string searchTerm, string searchString)
        {
            List<string> regexList = new List<string>();
            string term = "";
            if (searchTerm.Contains(" "))
            {
                var split = searchTerm.Split(" ");
                foreach (string item in split)
                {
                    term += item + @"\s";
                }
                char[] trim = new char[2] { 's', '\\' };
                term = term.Trim(trim);
            }
            else
            {
                term = searchTerm;
            }
            regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\b");
            regexList.Add(@"\b\." + term + @"\b");
            regexList.Add(@"\.\b" + term + @"\b");
            regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"s\b");
            regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\.\b");
            regexList.Add(@"\b" + term + @"\s\b");
            Regex searchRegex = new Regex(string.Join('|', regexList), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (searchRegex.IsMatch(searchString))
            {
                return new KeyValuePair<Regex, bool>(searchRegex, true);
            }
            return new KeyValuePair<Regex, bool>(null, false);
        }
```

This is the snippet of text that contains said term `"\nPulse 1: 100 bpm \nBlood Pressure 1:"` upon inspection of it I find no reason for there to me a mismatch, there are no odd white space characters, I have tried with **RegexOptions.SingleLine** and without it but there was no change. I am truly at a loss as to what string it is searching through, if it is different than the one I am searching through (and why) and how I could fix this issue.

Note: I know it doesn't look great, it's still a POC, but this code in particular actually finds the rectangles for about 150 search terms, and performs insanely fast in comparison to my previous version on iTextSharp 5, a 200 page document with 150 search terms and 5000 matches on the old version took ~45-60 seconds, the above version with higher accuracy (excluding this one case of "blood pressure") takes less than 5 seconds and averages on all documents less than a second.

**EDIT** I *may* have come to the conclusion that this is an issue within the **RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy** in that it appears to be searching one word at a time rather than the whole string at once, thus making find a phrase impossible through it's logic. This is my belief as I have found other results with multi word regex searches to be the same on other documents. If anyone has further knowledge on this please updated and inform as necessary

Well to discredit myself I created a pdf that contained a bunch of different content, including multi word patterns, and the method found it, but the underlying text is identical to the text that I have in the document where it is not finding it. I am not sure what would be causing this, it is very puzzling.

Comment: Your regexps seem to be rather redundant. You have a misplaced word boundary in some cases. I think you may use a single regex here, try `Regex searchRegex = new Regex($@"\.?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(term)}(?:s\b|(?!\w)[.\s]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Yeah, my regex statements are rather terrible, I was more worried with the issue I was having with finding it in some places, but not others. I appreciate this as it will definitely help with my lack of Regex expertise! One minor thing, would I be able to create the concatenated list of regex statements like I do in the first code block using this? 
**edit:** the reason is I have all of the terms going in through 1 regex statement, so it isn't just one term

Comment: Know what you pass to the regex engine, it will solve the problem. The regexps where `\b` is before or after a `\.` means there must be a word char before/after. It is wrong to think `\b\.a\b` will match in `.a`, it won't.

Comment: The regex is finding the words as it should, despite how terrible it is, but when the method RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy is called, it gets a different result, I believe this is because the string it uses to search through is different than the string I search through manually. This particular method also takes in only 1 regex statement, but I have 50+ terms, If I could simplify the regex statement as you suggest, but still have all 50+ terms in one statement, then that is the goal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I got your regex working with multiple terms. I appreciate your help with it :) 
The issue with the iText7 method is still unresolved

Comment: I have pinged the dev team.

Comment: Check out pdf2data.online - iText product dedicated specifically for data extraction. You can extract the coordinates and perform some post-processing as well

Comment: "(unfortunately cannot share, but I am trying to create one that can reproduce the issue)" - were you able to do this?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I haven't yet been able to reproduce the issue in a created document, but have a couple original scanned documents with this issue, I am trying to see if I can get de-identified versions of the documents and am hoping to have some success in sourcing a file today.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I have a document available to test, it is very heavily redacted and only has the text "Blood pressure" however the RegexBasedLocationExtractionStrategy with the following regex is not able to find it `Regex searchRegex = new Regex($@"\.?(?<!\w){Regex.Escape(searchTerm)}(?:s\b|(?!\w)[.\s]?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);` where searchTerm = "Blood Pressure". How can I get the file over to the dev team?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse If I have a document that I can share, how can I get said document over to the IText team? I have a deadline for this project and if the application can't deliver for the solution I have to find a different application :(

Comment: Do you have a support contract? If yes, then you can open an issue in our Jira and upload the document. Files uploaded to Jira will be automatically deleted 30 days after the issue is resolved so we definitely won't disclose your document.